# Meaning of $|w| ≡ 2 \mod 3$

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, modular-arithmetic

I'm new to formal language and automata theory and I was left alone with this exercise. The task is to define a formal grammar for given language.

$Σ \in \{a,b\}$

$L = \{ w \in Σ^*\, |\, |w| \equiv 2 \mod 3 \} $

I already solved tasks of that kind, but now i struggle to understand what $|w| \equiv 2 \mod 3$ means. $|w|$ means the length of $w$ right? Does $\equiv 2 \mod 3$ mean that $|w|$ should be $2$ (because 2 modulo 3 is 2)?

Comment: Note that this is a pure mathematics question (the context of formal languages is rather irrelevant) so you should have posted it to [math.SE].

Comment: But if he did not completely understand the mod notation, how could he be sure that it is more about mathematics than CS, @Raphael ? And he also asked about |w| (yes, only for reassurance), which is clearly formal languages.

Comment: @PeterLeupold Raphael is informing, not blaming. Obviously, if the asker had known that their question is better-suited to another site, they would have posted it there rather than here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $|w|$ is the length of $w$.

So $|w| \equiv 2 \mod 3$ means that the length of w divided by three should have the remainder 2. It should be from the set $\{2, 5, 8, \dots\}$.